# Как лучше всего перевести «user experience»?

Tags: перевод

В частности в этом вот отрывке текста:

> The display of an iOS device is at the heart of the user’s experience. Not only do people view beautiful text, graphics, and media on the display, they also physically interact with the Multi-Touch screen to drive their experience (even when they can’t see the screen).

Что здесь пользователи делают со своим опытом? Как это сказать по-человечески?

Comment: Интересно. Соглашусь с предудущими ответами > переводить по контексту, тем более, это реклама. Но, "сердце пользовательского интерфейса" как тут в одном из ответов звучит ужасно. Так как дословно переведено. Тогда уж, например, главная особенность при взаимодействии ... с пользователем.

Comment: @WinterDash Дословностью в этом переводе и не пахнет. Ужасно ли звучит — это мне трудно пока судить. Можно попробовать разобраться. Что именно вам мешает? Непонятно, что выражение значит? Если так, то почему? Что-нибудь другое? Если так, то что именно? Спасибо.

Comment: @WinterDash Маленькое замечание (хочется обратить внимание): вопрос задан довольно общий (как и приличествует этому сайту), потому и мой ответ тоже довольно общий. Ответ — это не перевод, а «технология» получения перевода в данном случае (для данного выражения: user experience). В общем, я отвечал на тот вопрос, который дан в заголовке темы, а всё, что написано в «теле» вопроса, я воспринимаю как разъяснительный комментарий к вопросу. Т. е., с другой стороны, эти обсуждения по конкретным переводам — довольно посторонние к теме, хотя и (частично) интересные…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Garrett's book title is translated into Russian as *Веб-дизайн: элементы опыта взаимодействия*.

It's quite an ugly calque in my opinion however it had rooted in the Russian web design argot.

Another option would be *пользовательские ожидания*. Your excerpt describes what do iOS users expect from their devices and apps they run.

Unfortunately *опыт взаимодействия* or *пользовательские ожидания* are not breakable in the same way the English phrases are.

Also, the original phrase ("to drive their [users'] experience") seems quite ostentatious and apparently just means "to do their stuff". I believe the author wanted to shift the focus from "using the device" or "using the app" to "getting things done the way they expect"

I think you'll have to invent your own translation or rephrase the sentence completely.

Something along these lines:

> Можно не глядя выполнять привычные действия, касаясь пальцами дисплея Multi-Touch.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, 'User Experience' usually cannot be translated in a consistent way throughout long texts and the translation must be contextually adapted.

I believe that the translation *пользовательские ожидания* proposed by Quassnoi is wrong. This is a common pitfall to understand the word 'Experience' here as life experience (`опыт`). Experience here means `впечатления`, `переживания`. Hence, `эргономика` is a far more narrow concept. Ergonomic quality of the product is only one part of the User Experience.

To sum up, I would translate as `опыт взаимодействия` if the author is talking about UX as a field of knowledge, job or discipline. In all other cases a replacement should be used.

For example,

> Дисплей — это главная особенность работы с устройствами на базе iOS. Впечатления людей состоят не только из просмотра красивых шрифтов и графики, но и физического взаимодействия с мультисенсорным дисплеем, которое может происходить даже, когда они не видят экран.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the accepted answer. And the reference to the translation of "user experience" as "опыт взаимодействия" does not hold much water either, IMHO. English word "experience" has 2 meanings (at least): 1. certain level of expertise and 2. a process of observation, encounter etc.
Russian word "опыт", on the other hand, only corresponds to the first meaning. This fact completely invalidates the referenced title translation.

I think a better translation would be something like "впечатление пользователя"

Comment: Actually, russian word "опыт" can mean both.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy разве? а можно пример использования второго варианта?

Answer (score 3):

The best term for "user experience" in Russian would be ***эргономика***. Yoiu can also use "***удобство работы***".

Comment: There is a big difference between ergonomics and the concept of UX. As an example, Dvorak keyboard layout for English is considered vastly superior and more efficient (thus, ergonomically optimized) than traditional QWERTY, yet the users are fimiliar, and expect, the latter, thus trying to put the former into, say, touchscreen interface, is not going to be user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, в таких рекламных текстах самое главное значение “user experience” – это «что-то очень хорошее». :) В общем, когда интерфейс надо ругать или хвалить, то говорят о “user experience”… Потому что, понятное дело, интерфейс ругают или хвалят за интуитивность: насколько представления пользователя о выполнении задачи соответствуют тому, что программа реально делает… Воспоминания о таком соответствии или несоответствии — это и есть “experience”… Русского слова нет – есть только приближения.

«Философские» вещи вроде овеществлённых воспоминаний (Google: “an event or occurrence which leaves an impression on someone”) при переводе нужно просто опускать. По-русски «опыт» — это что-то такое, что прямо действует на принятие решений; а по-английски — ещё и что-то такое, что предназначено для простого воспоминания или для применения в качестве отвлечённой «идеи»: мысли, которую можно с чем-то сопоставить, куда-то прикрутить, сравнить с чем-то и т. п. Разница даже не в значении, а в предназначении слова: если во фразе “audition day is an enjoyable experience for any seven-year old” (взята из того же словаря) перевести буквально слово “experience”, то всё, в общем, нормально, только непонятно, зачем ребёнок использует этот опыт: какие решения он на его основе принимает. Потому ненатурально. С английской фразой такого недоумения не возникает: ясно, что он будет этот опыт *помнить*, и это главное.

Следовательно, когда надо переводить такие тексты, надо говорить о том, что есть, то есть об интерфейсе, о его интуитивности, и проч. В крайнем случае – действительно о впечатлениях, хотя они, конечно, – вещь подчинённая. О том, чего нет (всякая философия), говорить не надо. В качестве иллюстрации (предположим, что речь идёт именно о смартфонах):

> Экран смартфона-яблочника – вот что привлекает в нём больше всего. Люди не только просматривают привлекательные тексты, графику и видео на экране, они и физически взаимодействуют с экраном-мультитачем, чтобы управлять приложениями (даже если экран – вне поля зрения). …

Согласитесь, со словом «управлять» связаны те самые положительные ощущения, которые связаны и со словом “experience”. Управляемость! Это хорошо…

Comment: Quite nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to literally replace *words* or word combinations with certain dictionary items. Translation is  an attempt to express the same *sense* with the means of the target language. IMO, words like **опыт** or **впечатление** don't belong here. Here's my suggestion:

> Дисплей устройства от Эппл - всегда в центре
>   внимания пользователя. Он не только разглядывает на экране изящные
>   текст, графику и видео - при взаимодействии с устройством он ещё и
>   физически контактирует с многофункциональным сенсорным экраном (порой
>   даже не глядя на него).

Answer (score -2):

Я бы это перевёл как

> Восприятие пользователя (звучит лучше)
>
> или же,
>
> Пользовательское восприятие (звучит хуже)